# PHP adding a pdf to email

Tags: php, email, pdf, encode

I have successful created a pdf file on a website. What I would like to do is send that pdf as an attachment in an email. So far it appears that I have successfully attached the file however when attempting to open the attachment acrobat reader give me this error message:

```
Acrobat could not open 'example2.pdf' because it is either not a supported type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)
```

I think this error message has hit the nail on the head, below is my code does anyone know what needs to be changed? Thanks advance :)

```
$to = "me@domain"; 
$from = "me@domain.com"; 
$subject = "send email with pdf attachment"; 
$message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";
// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());
// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;
// attachment name
$filename = "example.pdf";
// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode("/include/pdf.php?reportid=849980"));
// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;
// message
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;
// attachment
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";
// send message
mail($to, $subject, "", $headers);
```

Comment: For the MAX_INTth time on this site, do NOT build your own mime emails. use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) to do it for you.

Comment: Use a mail library that does attachment handling for you. There is no need to write everything yourself, two common ones are Phpmailer and Swiftmailer. Edit: @MarcB: lol

Comment: what they said, with knobs on!

Comment: does your PDF work in Acrobat when you try to download it instead?

Comment: Hi Zathrus. Yes, I just saved the file and viewed it in acrobat reader no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = "example.pdf";
// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode("/include/pdf.php?reportid=849980"));
```

looks to be your problem. Your attachment does appear to be the pdf, but instead a php page... also you need to binary (rb) read-in the file contents of the pdf, something like:

```
$filename = 'example.pdf';  
$fileloc = '/path/to/pdf/'.$filename;   

$filehandle = fopen($fileloc, 'rb');
$data = fread($filehandle, filesize($fileloc));
fclose($filehandle);                

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but the attachment is empty.

Comment: ok, do "var_dump($data); exit;" after fclose() to verify that the pdf has been read into $data correctly

Comment: this is the tutorial you followed, right? http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/217105/generate-a-pdf-and-send-as-attachment

Comment: Yes thats the tutorial, but I just pointed to a pdf file instead of creating one.

Comment: I did try the var_dump but it put this message in the browser "bool(false)" and the attachment is still empty. Thanks for you help with this :)

Comment: then the file path to your pdf is incorrect, in which case you should be getting a error like "failed to open stream: no such file or directory" but it appears you might have error message display suppressed

Comment: I used to use this same mailer demo script, and I just found & ran it, works great. Only difference between yours and mine is the snippet above I posted so once you get the pdf filepath correct the attachment should work fine

Comment: You are right, it does say that it failed to open stream, but I have checked the file location and it is accurate. I take it then that there is either an issue with it reading a php file which is generating the pdf or it isn't treating the 'reportid=849980' part of the file location as a parameter being passed to the PHP file...

Comment: You can't use a query string in a file path... Likely you will need to alter your "pdf.php" to save the generated pdf to a file on your server somewhere (put in /tmp if you run into permission issues) and then fopen/fread the static pdf for the mailer attachment. Just try the mailer script with an existing pdf file to verify the attachment part works first.

Comment: I tried it with a pdf and it worked, just like you said. You are right again, I'm just going to have to try and figure a way to save the pdf. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: no problem. Try a few things on your own first and if you get stuck make a new question for pdf.php report part and post a link to that question as a reply to this comment, I'll check it out later.