# Attach pdf generated with TCPDF sending mail with mail PHP function

Tags: php, attachment, tcpdf, email-attachments

I want send a pdf generated with TCPDF using mail Php function.

If I send a simple mail like this works: mail('xxx@ne.es', 'My Subject', $message);

The pdf is generated well, but when I want attach pdf in header not works.

This is my code:

```
$pdfdoc=$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'S');

 $separator = md5(time());

        $eol = PHP_EOL;
// Send
        $filename = "_Desiredfilename.pdf";

        // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)

        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

        ///////////HEADERS INFORMATION////////////
        // main header (multipart mandatory) message
        $headers  = "From: Sender_Name<sender@domain.com>".$eol;
        $headers .= "Bcc: email@domain.com".$eol;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
        $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

        // message
        $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
        $headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

        // attachment
        $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
        $headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
        $headers .= "--".$separator."--";


        //Email message
        mail('xxx@gmail.com', 'prova', 'hola', $headers);
```

When is the problem?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: What is your error? What have you tried?

Comment: The problem is that mail no is sended.

Comment: Could be problem in php.ini configuration?

Comment: is pdf getting saved properly ? is it getting saved automatically when you run script or it prompt message to save ?

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572280/php-adding-a-pdf-to-email

Comment: @Mahendra with S option pdf is generated like String

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you too. I have checked and its works well. please try it.Before that please check the "php.ini" for mail and Check the pdf file was created or not.

```
$pdfdoc=$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'F');

        // Send
        $files = "file.pdf";



        ///////////HEADERS INFORMATION////////////
        // boundary
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

        // headers for attachment
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

         // multipart boundary
        $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";

        // preparing attachments
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
            $fp     = @fopen($files,"rb");
            $data   = @fread($fp,filesize($files));
                    @fclose($fp);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files)."\"\n" .
            "Content-Description: ".basename($files)."\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files)."\"; size=".filesize($files).";\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";


        //Email message
        mail('xxx@gmail.com', 'prova', 'hola', $headers);
```

or include this function in your code, use this function for sent multi-attachment file.
this one worked well . please try this.

```
/* 
     * Function Name: sentMail
     * Scope        : Sent Mail Function with CC , BCC and Attachment files..
     * Input        : Recipient Name            => $recipientName   // (Required)
     *                Recipient MailId(Many)    => $recipientMailId // (Required & Array Format)
     *                Subject Content           => $subjectContent  // (Required)
     *                Message Content           => $messageContent  // (Required)
     *                Sender MailId             => $senderMailId    // (Required)
     *                Sender Name(Many)         => $senderName      // (Required)
     *                Recipient CC MailId       => $recipientCCMailId   //(Optional & Array Format)
     *                Recipient BCC MailId      => $recipientBCCMailId  //(Optional & Array Format)
     *                Attachment Files          => $attachmentFiles     //(Optional & Array Format)
     * Output       : Sent mail to the Recipient.
     */
    public function sentMail($recipientName,$recipientMailId,$subjectContent,$messageContent,$senderName,$senderMailId,$recipientCCMailId,$recipientBCCMailId,$attachmentFiles)
    {
        try 
        {
            /*Get the Mulitple Recipient CC MailId*/
            if(isset($recipientCCMailId)){
                if(count($recipientCCMailId)>1){
                    $recipientCCMailId = implode(',',$recipientCCMailId);
                }
                else{
                    $recipientCCMailId = $recipientCCMailId[0];
                }
            }

            /*Get the Mulitple Recipient BCC MailId*/
            if(isset($recipientBCCMailId)){
                if(count($recipientBCCMailId)>1){
                    $recipientBCCMailId = implode(',',$recipientBCCMailId);
                }
                else{
                    $recipientBCCMailId = $recipientBCCMailId[0];
                }
            }

            /*** Mail Contents Starts ***/
                $subj = $subjectContent;
                $msg ="";

                /*Get the Mulitple Recipient BCC MailId*/
                if(count($recipientMailId)>1){
                    $recipientMailId = implode(',',$recipientMailId);
                    $msg .="Dear, <b>All</b>\r <br>";
                }
                else{
                    $recipientMailId = $recipientMailId[0];
                    $msg .="Dear, <b>".ucwords($user_name)."</b> \r <br>";
                }
                $msg .=$messageContent."\r <br><br>";
                $msg .="Thank you"."\r\n\n <br>";
                $msg .=$senderName."\r\n\n <br><br>";

                $headers ="";

                /** Get the Mulitple Attachment files and Attachment Process Starts **/
                if(isset($attachmentFiles)){
                    $headers .= "From: ".$senderMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Cc: ".$recipientCCMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Bcc: ".$recipientBCCMailId."\r\n";
                    // boundary
                    $semi_rand = md5(time());
                    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

                    // headers for attachment
                    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
                     // multipart boundary
                    $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $msg . "\n\n";

                    // preparing attachments
                    for($i=0;$i<count($attachmentFiles);$i++)
                    {
                        if(is_file($attachmentFiles[$i]))
                        { 
                            $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                            $fp     = @fopen($attachmentFiles[$i],"rb");
                            $data   = @fread($fp,filesize($attachmentFiles[$i]));
                                      @fclose($fp);
                            $data   = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                            $msg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($attachmentFiles[$i])."\"\n" .
                            "Content-Description: ".basename($attachmentFiles[$i])."\n" .
                            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($attachmentFiles[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($attachmentFiles[$i]).";\n" .
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                        }
                     }
                    $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                }
                /** Attachment Process Ends **/
                else{
                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
                    //$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "From: ".$senderMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Cc: ".$recipientCCMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Bcc: ".$recipientBCCMailId."\r\n";
                }
            /*** Mail Contents Ends ***/    
            $sent_mail=mail($recipientMailId,$subj,$msg,$headers); 
            if($sent_mail)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            getConnection('close');
            echo "Caught Exception:",$e->getMessage();
        } 
    }
```

and you edited this one by this parameter as specified format in the DTD of the function.

```
sentMail($recipientName,$recipientMailId,$subjectContent,$messageContent,$senderName,$senderMailId,$recipientCCMailId,$recipientBCCMailId,$attachmentFiles);
```

here,

```
$recipientName = "sam";
$recipientMailId = array("xxx@gmail.com");
$subjectContent = "this is sample pdf attachment over email";
$messageContent = "this is sample pdf attachment over email";
$senderMailId   = "sender@gmail.com"
$senderName     = "sender";
$recipientCCMailId = array("xxx@gmail.com");
$recipientBCCMailId = array("xxx@gmail.com");
$attachmentFiles = array("filename.pdf");

sentMail($recipientName,$recipientMailId,$subjectContent,$messageContent,$senderName,$senderMailId,$recipientCCMailId,$recipientBCCMailId,$attachmentFiles);
```

Comment: Thanks, I go to prove it. If I generate the pdf with F option, the pdf is saved in server? Only temporal? Thanks

Comment: I don't want save pdf in server, If is possible I want generate like String

Comment: after you successfully sent the mail with pdf. You have delete that temporal file using "unlink($files)".

Comment: Sorry but what is the folder that save pdf? I obtain this error: Warning: fopen(EnglishSummerFun-Inscription.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/marc/work/english_summer_fun/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 7651
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: EnglishSummerFun-Inscription.pdf

Comment: check the folder permission is 755 please change the folder permission to 777.

Comment: Now the file is generated well, and mail sended, but I don't receive the file like attachment I receive  file like string. This is the mail: hola Marc

--==Multipart_Boundary_x627f41e8d96803ad75b81b6693fcd980x
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="EnglishSummerFun-Inscription.pdf"
Content-Description: EnglishSummerFun-Inscription.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="EnglishSummerFun-Inscription.pdf"; size=61637;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9MKNyAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZSAvUGFyZW50IDEgMCBSIC9MYXN0
TW9k............

Comment: please try that function i have edited in this answer. from that you got a solution for this. its working well for me.